# how to prove $G$ is an abelian group under $*$ (called the real numbers mod 1)

Tags: proof-writing, binary-operations, associativity

Let $G = \{x \in \mathbb{R}~|~0\leq x < 1\}$ and for $x,y \in G$ let $x*y$ be the fractional part of $x+y$ i.e $x*y = x + y - [x + y]$ where $[a]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $a$. I need help proving $*$ is a well defined binary operation on $G$ and that $G$ is an abelian group under $*$.

To prove that $*$ is well defined, I rely on the assumption that +,- is well defined in the set of real numbers. evaluating the brackets [] is also well-defined in the set of real numbers. (is this an okay assumption?)

To prove $*$ is associative, (I imagine because +,- is associative, so will *?) I show that $(x*y)*z = x*(y*z)$ $$(x*y)*z =(x+y-[x+y])*z = x+y-[x+y]+z - [x+y-[x+y]+z]$$ $$x*(y*z) = x*(y+z - [y+z]) = x + y + z - [y+z] - [x+y+z - [y+z]]$$ rearranging $$(x*y)*z = x+y+z-[x+y]-[x+y+z-[x+y]]$$ $$x*(y*z) = x+y+z-[y+z]-[x+y+z-[y+z]]$$ I am not so sure that these two are equal. I don't see how distributing the $-$ to remove the terms $[x+y]$ and $[y+z]$ is fair (ex: $x = y = \frac{1}{2}$ so $x*y = .5+.5-[.5]-[.5]$ yields a different answer than $x*y = .5+.5-[.5+.5]$

The identity element would be $0$, the inverse would have to be $-x$ which isn't in $G$. What am I doing wrong?

edit: commutativity would be proven by showing $x*y = y*x$ which is easy to show $x+y - [x+y] = y+x - [y+x]$ right?

Comment: For a proof see for example [here](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/the-reals-mod-the-integers-are-a-group/).

Comment: I'm actually using that to check my solutions for the exercises in D&F. I'd like hints/corrections for my proof before I check the solution though.

Comment: You write "I am not sure that these two are equal". For this, the solution is exactly what you need.

Comment: You have justified that $*$ is well-defined as an operation *on the reals*. However, you still must show that $x*y\in G$ for all $x,y\in G.$

Comment: Also, subtraction is not an associative operation.

Comment: Commutativity and identity look fine. As for inverses, suppose $0<x<1,$ try setting $x*y=0,$ and solve for $y.$

Comment: I think the best way to think about this group is as rotations in the plane. $x\in G$ signifies rotation of $360x$ degrees.

Comment: To prove that $G$ is closed under $*$ can you do $x * y = x + y - [x+y]$ and show that the domains are $(0\leq x < 1) + (0 \leq y < 1) - (0 \leq [x+y] < 2)$ where the brackets are evaluated to be an integer. Does that prove it or do I have to go further? @CameronBuie

Comment: @CameronBuie solving for y, $x*y = x + y - [x+y] = 0$ then $y = [x+y] - x$ how do I separate x and y?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the solution proves associativity by cancelling out terms by distributing the $-$ sign. I have issues with that and it doesn't address them.

Comment: To prove closure under $*,$ remember that $[x+y]$ is by definition the greatest integer $n$ such that $n\le x+y.$ In particular, then, we have $$[x+y]\le x+y<[x+y]+1.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: As for finding the inverse of $x,$ remember that $[x+y]$ is an integer, so if $x*y=0,$ it follows that $x+y$ is itself an integer! (Do you see why?) Since $0<x<1$ and $0\le y<1,$ what integer can $x+y$ be? What does that mean $y$ *must* be?

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you for your help. The inverse has to be $y = 1-x$ since $x+y$ is to be the integer 1. I forgot to reply and thank you :p

Comment: @Obliv: Absolutely right! That works for all non-zero $x\in G.$

Comment: also, for the part about associativity in case anyone else is wondering, the bracketed section inside of the bracketed section can be treated almost like a constant in an integral. It won't change the value of the bracketed section since it's an integer in itself so it's okay to take it out to cancel terms. If it were single values that were not integers, however, it would not be okay to cancel out. i.e $[x+[a+b]] = [x]+[a+b]$ but not $[x+a+b] = [x]+[a+b]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of your group $(G, *)$ as $(\mathbb{R}, +)/\mathbb{Z}$: That is, the reals under addition modded out by the integers.

This clearly works because we are essentially saying that is $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x = \mathbb{Z} + y$ in $\mathbb{R} /\mathbb{Z}$.
This has the same effect as “truncation”, but is now a nice subgroup
Hence,

$$
(G, *) \simeq (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}, +)
$$

To imagine this, realize that $\mathbb{R}$ just contains shifted copies of $[0, 1)$ all laid down one next to the other. So, we simply “collapse” all these copies together for this construction to work out.

Now, for this to be a group, we need the kernel of the map $$\phi: (\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{R}, +) /\mathbb{Z}$$

to be a normal subgroup. Since the kernel of a quotient map is the quotienting subgroup itself, we simply need to
show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. This is obvious in abelian groups.

Comment: As you're defining it, $\;[0,1)\;$ is not even a subgroup of $\;(\Bbb R,+)\;$ , so that map $\;\phi\;$, whatever it is,  is not a group homomorphism and its kernel is irrelevant, in my opinion. Also, if you're taking the *usual* group $\;(\Bbb R,+)\;$ , then this is an abelian group, so **any** subgroup is normal.

Comment: Whoops, you're totally right. What I meant to use was $\mathbb{R} /\ \mathbb{Z}$ which does the same thing (but is actually a subgroup)

Comment: @Joanpemo - the proof should be correct now. Could you retract your downvote if it is?

Comment: Sorry but can you prove it is an abelian group by showing that $(G,*)$ satisfies the abelian group axioms instead of treating it as a different group (no idea what kernels, quotient sub groups, etc. are) I'm still a beginner to group theory so I don't have access to your methods in my knowledge yet.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I've never downvoted a posted answer for a tiny mistake and even less after a few minutes. Sorry, it wasn't me.

Comment: @Joanpemo - Heh, all right. I've faced some weird situations with people insta-downvoting, so I was checking :) Thanks!

Comment: @Obliv - that will however, be a completely different proof. I'll try and do this once I have the time :)

Answer (score 3):

> To prove $∗$ is associative

Let $a,b,c\in G$.
\begin{align*}
(a*b)*c &= (a+b-[a+b])*c \\
   &= a+b+c-[a+b]-\left[a+b+c-[a+b]\right]
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
a*(b*c) &= a+b+c-[b+c]-\left[a+b+c-[b+c]\right]
\end{align*}

Given $0\le a,b,c < 1, [a+b]$ and $[b+c]$ must be either zero or one individually, for a total of four possible cases.  In the cases when both are zeros or ones, clearly $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$.

Consider the case when $[a+b]=1$ and $[b+c]=0$.  Necessarily $1 \le a+b < 2, b+c< 1$ and $1\le a+b+c< 2\implies [a+b+c] = 1$ and $[a+b+c-1] = 0$. Therefore, $(a*b)* c=a+b+c-1-[a+b+c-1]=a+b+c-1$, whereas $a*(b* c)=a+b+c-[a+b+c]=a+b+c-1$; i.e. $(a* b)* c = a*(b* c)$.

Similar argument applies when $[a+b]=0$ and $[b+c]=1$.  This covers all four cases.

Hence $G$ is associative over $*$.